# Converting code for driver IC IL0373 to SSD1680

Tags: display

I'm working on epaper display, and writing code in Segger embedded studio for nRF52840DK.

Below is code for Driver IC IL0373 epaper display, has no response on paper display as it have driver IC SSD1680 [here](https://github.com/leonrinkel/nRF52-eink-epaper/tree/master/src)

Below *paper.c*

```
#include "paper.h"
#include <string.h>

#include "nrf_gpio.h"
#include "nrf_delay.h"
#include "nrf_drv_spi.h"

#define PAPER_RST_PIN 13
#define PAPER_DC_PIN  14

#define PAPER_SPI_INSTANCE 0
#define PAPER_SPI_SS_PIN   29
#define PAPER_SPI_MOSI_PIN 4
#define PAPER_SPI_SCK_PIN  3

#define PAPER_BYTE_WIDTH ((PAPER_PIXEL_WIDTH % 8 == 0) ? PAPER_PIXEL_WIDTH / 8 : PAPER_PIXEL_WIDTH / 8 + 1)
#define PAPER_BYTE_HEIGHT PAPER_PIXEL_HEIGHT
#define PAPER_BUFLEN PAPER_BYTE_WIDTH * PAPER_BYTE_HEIGHT

#define PAPER_CMD_PWR  0x01
#define PAPER_CMD_BTST 0x06
#define PAPER_CMD_PON  0x04
#define PAPER_CMD_PSR  0x00
#define PAPER_CMD_PLL  0x30
#define PAPER_CMD_TRES 0x61
#define PAPER_CMD_VDCD 0x82
#define PAPER_CMD_VCOM 0x50
#define PAPER_CMD_LUT_VCDC 0x20
#define PAPER_CMD_LUT_WW 0x21
#define PAPER_CMD_LUT_BW 0x22
#define PAPER_CMD_LUT_WB 0x23
#define PAPER_CMD_LUT_BB 0x24
#define PAPER_CMD_DISP 0x12

static const nrf_drv_spi_t spi = NRF_DRV_SPI_INSTANCE(PAPER_SPI_INSTANCE);

static uint8_t paper_cmd_pwr[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_PWR,
  0x03, 0x00, 0x2b, 0x2b, 0x03,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_btst[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_BTST,
  0x17, 0x17, 0x17,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_pon[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_PON,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_psr[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_PSR,
  0xbf, 0x0d,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_pll[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_PLL,
  0x3a,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_tres[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_TRES,
  PAPER_PIXEL_WIDTH,
  (PAPER_PIXEL_HEIGHT >> 8) & 0xff,
  PAPER_PIXEL_HEIGHT & 0xff,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_vdcd[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_VDCD,
  0x28,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_vcom[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_VCOM,
  0x97
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_lut_vcdc[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_LUT_VCDC,
  0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
  0x60, 0x28, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x00, 0x12, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_lut_ww[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_LUT_WW,
  0x40, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
  0x90, 0x28, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x40, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0xA0, 0x12, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_lut_bw[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_LUT_BW,
  0x40, 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
  0x90, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03,
  0x40, 0x0A, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0xA0, 0x0E, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_lut_wb[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_LUT_WB,
  0x80, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
  0x90, 0x28, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x80, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x50, 0x12, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_lut_bb[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_LUT_BB,
  0x80, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
  0x90, 0x28, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x80, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x50, 0x12, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
};

static uint8_t paper_cmd_disp[] = {
  PAPER_CMD_DISP,
};

static uint8_t paper_buffer[PAPER_BUFLEN];
static uint8_t paper_prev_buffer[PAPER_BUFLEN];

static void paper_begin_command(void) {
  nrf_gpio_pin_clear(PAPER_DC_PIN);
}

static void paper_begin_data(void) {
  nrf_gpio_pin_set(PAPER_DC_PIN);
}

static ret_code_t paper_tx_cmd(uint8_t *cmd, uint8_t length) {
  ret_code_t ret;

  paper_begin_command();
  ret = nrf_drv_spi_transfer(&spi, cmd, 1, NULL, 0);
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  if (length - 1 > 0) {
    paper_begin_data();
    ret = nrf_drv_spi_transfer(&spi, cmd + 1, length - 1, NULL, 0);
    if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;
  }

  return ret;
}

static void paper_reset(void) {
  nrf_gpio_pin_clear(PAPER_RST_PIN);
  nrf_delay_ms(200);
  nrf_gpio_pin_set(PAPER_RST_PIN);
  nrf_delay_ms(200);
}

static ret_code_t paper_tx_lut(void) {
  ret_code_t ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_vcom, sizeof(paper_cmd_vcom));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_lut_vcdc, sizeof(paper_cmd_lut_vcdc));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_lut_ww, sizeof(paper_cmd_lut_ww));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_lut_bw, sizeof(paper_cmd_lut_bw));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_lut_wb, sizeof(paper_cmd_lut_wb));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_lut_bb, sizeof(paper_cmd_lut_bb));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  return ret;
}

static ret_code_t _paper_display(void) {
  ret_code_t ret;

  /*
   * TODO transfer chunks of 256 bytes rather than calling nrf_drv_spi_transfer
   * for each byte.
   */

  uint8_t command[1];

  command[0] = 0x10;
  ret = paper_tx_cmd(command, 1);
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  paper_begin_data();
  for (int i = 0; i < PAPER_BUFLEN; i++) {
    ret = nrf_drv_spi_transfer(&spi, paper_prev_buffer + i, 1, NULL, 0);
    if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;
  }

  nrf_delay_ms(10);

  /*
   * TODO i'm not yet sure about the purpose of sending the previous buffer too.
   * just sending 0x00s works pretty good. when sending the actual previous
   * image buffer, it looks like sections that have not changed become kinda
   * dirty / greyish (which could be useful because one can use three colors).
   */

  // memcpy(paper_prev_buffer, paper_buffer, PAPER_BUFLEN);

  command[0] = 0x13;
  ret = paper_tx_cmd(command, 1);
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  paper_begin_data();
  for (int i = 0; i < PAPER_BUFLEN; i++) {
    ret = nrf_drv_spi_transfer(&spi, paper_buffer + i, 1, NULL, 0);
    if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;
  }

  nrf_delay_ms(10);

  ret = paper_tx_lut();
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_disp, sizeof(paper_cmd_disp));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  nrf_delay_ms(100); // TODO use busy pin rather than arbitrary delays

  return ret;
}

ret_code_t paper_init(void) {
  ret_code_t ret;

  nrf_drv_spi_config_t spi_config = NRF_DRV_SPI_DEFAULT_CONFIG;
  spi_config.ss_pin   = PAPER_SPI_SS_PIN;
  spi_config.mosi_pin = PAPER_SPI_MOSI_PIN;
  spi_config.sck_pin  = PAPER_SPI_SCK_PIN;

  ret = nrf_drv_spi_init(&spi, &spi_config, NULL, NULL);
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  nrf_gpio_cfg_output(PAPER_RST_PIN);
  nrf_gpio_cfg_output(PAPER_DC_PIN);

  paper_reset();

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_pwr, sizeof(paper_cmd_pwr));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_btst, sizeof(paper_cmd_btst));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_pon, sizeof(paper_cmd_pon));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_psr, sizeof(paper_cmd_psr));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_pll, sizeof(paper_cmd_pll));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_tres, sizeof(paper_cmd_tres));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  ret = paper_tx_cmd(paper_cmd_vdcd, sizeof(paper_cmd_vdcd));
  if (ret != NRF_SUCCESS) return ret;

  memset(paper_buffer, 0xff, PAPER_BUFLEN);
  memset(paper_prev_buffer, 0x00, PAPER_BUFLEN);

  return ret;
}

void paper_uninit(void) {
  // TODO uninit spi and free buffers
}

void paper_pixel_draw(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint32_t color) {
  ASSERT(x < PAPER_PIXEL_WIDTH);
  ASSERT(y < PAPER_PIXEL_HEIGHT);

  int bitn = y * PAPER_PIXEL_WIDTH + x;
  int byten = bitn / 8;
  bitn = 8 - bitn % 8 - 1;

  if (color == 0) paper_buffer[byten] |= 1UL << (bitn);
  else paper_buffer[byten] &= ~(1UL << (bitn));
}

void paper_rect_draw(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t width, uint16_t height, uint32_t color) {
  ASSERT(x + width < PAPER_PIXEL_WIDTH);
  ASSERT(y + height < PAPER_PIXEL_HEIGHT);

  for (uint16_t _x = x; _x < x + width; _x++)
    for (uint16_t _y = y; _y < y + height; _y++)
      paper_pixel_draw(_x, _y, color);
}

void paper_display(void) {
  APP_ERROR_CHECK(_paper_display());
}

void paper_rotation_set(nrf_lcd_rotation_t rotation) {
  UNUSED_PARAMETER(rotation);

  // TODO
}

void paper_display_invert(bool invert) {
  UNUSED_PARAMETER(invert);

  // TODO
}
```

The e-paper display I have are with SSD1680 IC, [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_EPD/blob/master/src/drivers/Adafruit_SSD1680.h)

In Adafruit Library I found the following parameters

For SSD1680, [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_EPD/blob/master/src/drivers/Adafruit_SSD1680.h)

```
#define SSD1680_DRIVER_CONTROL 0x01
#define SSD1680_GATE_VOLTAGE 0x03
#define SSD1680_SOURCE_VOLTAGE 0x04
#define SSD1680_PROGOTP_INITIAL 0x08
#define SSD1680_PROGREG_INITIAL 0x09
#define SSD1680_READREG_INITIAL 0x0A
#define SSD1680_BOOST_SOFTSTART 0x0C
#define SSD1680_DEEP_SLEEP 0x10
#define SSD1680_DATA_MODE 0x11
#define SSD1680_SW_RESET 0x12
#define SSD1680_TEMP_CONTROL 0x18
#define SSD1680_TEMP_WRITE 0x1A
#define SSD1680_MASTER_ACTIVATE 0x20
#define SSD1680_DISP_CTRL1 0x21
#define SSD1680_DISP_CTRL2 0x22
#define SSD1680_WRITE_RAM1 0x24
#define SSD1680_WRITE_RAM2 0x26
#define SSD1680_WRITE_VCOM 0x2C
#define SSD1680_READ_OTP 0x2D
#define SSD1680_READ_STATUS 0x2F
#define SSD1680_WRITE_LUT 0x32
#define SSD1680_WRITE_BORDER 0x3C
#define SSD1680_SET_RAMXPOS 0x44
#define SSD1680_SET_RAMYPOS 0x45
#define SSD1680_SET_RAMXCOUNT 0x4E
#define SSD1680_SET_RAMYCOUNT 0x4F
```

For IL0373, [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_EPD/blob/master/src/drivers/Adafruit_IL0373.h)

```
#define IL0373_PANEL_SETTING 0x00
#define IL0373_POWER_SETTING 0x01
#define IL0373_POWER_OFF 0x02
#define IL0373_POWER_OFF_SEQUENCE 0x03
#define IL0373_POWER_ON 0x04
#define IL0373_POWER_ON_MEASURE 0x05
#define IL0373_BOOSTER_SOFT_START 0x06
#define IL0373_DEEP_SLEEP 0x07
#define IL0373_DTM1 0x10
#define IL0373_DATA_STOP 0x11
#define IL0373_DISPLAY_REFRESH 0x12
#define IL0373_DTM2 0x13
#define IL0373_PDTM1 0x14
#define IL0373_PDTM2 0x15
#define IL0373_PDRF 0x16
#define IL0373_LUT1 0x20
#define IL0373_LUTWW 0x21
#define IL0373_LUTBW 0x22
#define IL0373_LUTWB 0x23
#define IL0373_LUTBB 0x24
#define IL0373_PLL 0x30
#define IL0373_CDI 0x50
#define IL0373_RESOLUTION 0x61
#define IL0373_VCM_DC_SETTING 0x82
#define IL0373_PARTIAL_WINDOW 0x90
#define IL0373_PARTIAL_ENTER 0x91
#define IL0373_PARTIAL_EXIT 0x92
```

I need help with how to convert the use of IL0373 in *paper.c* to SSD1680, or is it even possible to do so?